# Utilizar o Google oauth2 sem passar pela página de login do google

Tags: google, oauth2

Estou começando a implementar o uso da autentucação do google oAuth na minha aplicação. alguns testes feitos funcionando e tals, mas sempre tendo de passar pela tela de login e consentimento do google. Gostaria de saber se é possível eu fazer todo o processo de autenticação tendo a minha aplicação os campos de email e senha e através das APIs do google eu fazer a devida autenticação?

Comment: Você está fazendo essa aplicação em que linguagem, consegue demonstrar o que tente e detalhar melhor para nós?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível, a utilização do OAuth é exatamente para permitir o login por meio de outro serviço. O usuário da sua aplicação irá logar no serviço que permite OAuth e este serviço irá informar se o usuário tem ou não acesso autorizado.

A imagem abaixo, em inglês, mostra como esse tipo de autenticação funciona.

[image: OAuth]

Sua aplicação envia a solicitação, o usuário loga no serviço/autoriza o acesso e o Google te responde com as certificações do usuário.

Apesar de em inglês, a Google possui uma [documentação](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) bastante extensa sobre o protocolo OAuth, recomendo uma lida.

Comment: Muito mais completa, parabens

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível. O Google faz grandes esforços para se certificar de que apenas os seres humanos podem fornecer senhas, e não aplicativos que atuam em nome dos usuários. Querem garantir também a ciência do usuário dos dados que serão acessados. Além de garantir a segurança na informação circulado.